# Markov Analysis, Formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting, markov-chains

I have a program that reads in a big chunk of text from a text file and then randomizes the content to display back as a short story based on the content of the text. The program *works* but the last part, where I am displaying the material is super clunky and not efficient and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how I could more efficiently take in the text and then display it as a string to the user but allow it to span multiple lines (wrap text, essentially) so that it is not just a giant string of text continuing to the right of the console.

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import sys

import random

# global variables
suffix_map = {}        # map from prefixes to a list of suffixes
prefix = ()            # current tuple of words
big_list = []

def process_file(filename, order=2):
    """Reads a file and performs Markov analysis.

    filename: string
    order: integer number of words in the prefix

    returns: map from prefix to list of possible suffixes.
    """
    fp = open(filename)

    for line in fp:
        for word in line.rstrip().split():
            process_word(word, order)


def process_word(word, order=3):
    """Processes each word.

    word: string
    order: integer

    During the first few iterations, all we do is store up the words;
    after that we start adding entries to the dictionary.
    """
    global prefix
    if len(prefix) < order:
        prefix += (word,)
        return

    try:
        suffix_map[prefix].append(word)
    except KeyError:
        # if there is no entry for this prefix, make one
        suffix_map[prefix] = [word]

    prefix = shift(prefix, word)


def random_text(n=300):
    """Generates random wordsfrom the analyzed text.

    Starts with a random prefix from the dictionary.

    n: number of words to generate
    """
    global big_list
    # choose a random prefix (not weighted by frequency)
    start = random.choice(list(suffix_map.keys()))

    for i in range(n):
        suffixes = suffix_map.get(start, None)
        if suffixes == None:
            random_text(n-i)
            return
        # choose a random suffix
        word = random.choice(suffixes)
        big_list.append(word + " ")
        start = shift(start, word)


def shift(t, word):
    """Forms a new tuple by removing the head and adding word to the tail.

    t   : tuple of strings
    word: string

    Returns: tuple of strings
    """
    return t[1:] + (word,)


def list_to_str_format():
    global big_list
    whole = " ".join(str(i) for i in big_list)

    # 25 words per line
    l1 = big_list[:25]
    l2 = big_list[26:50]
    l3 = big_list[51:75]
    l4 = big_list[76:100]
    l5 = big_list[101:125]
    l6 = big_list[126:150]
    l7 = big_list[151:175]
    l8 = big_list[176:200]
    l9 = big_list[201:225]
    l10 = big_list[226:250]
    l11 = big_list[256:275]
    l12 = big_list[276:300]

    str_1 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l1).capitalize()
    str_2 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l2)
    str_3 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l3)
    str_4 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l4)
    str_5 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l5)
    str_6 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l6)
    str_7 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l7)
    str_8 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l8)
    str_9 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l9)
    str_10 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l10)
    str_11 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l11)
    str_12 = " ".join(str(i) for i in l12)

    print(str_1)
    print(str_2)
    print(str_3)
    print(str_4)
    print(str_5)
    print(str_6)
    print(str_7)
    print(str_8)
    print(str_9)
    print(str_10)
    print(str_11)
    print(str_12)


def main(filename, n=300, order=3):
    try:
        n = int(n)
        order = int(order)
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Usage: %d filename [# of words] [prefix length]' % e)
    else:
        process_file(filename, order)
        random_text(n)
        list_to_str_format()
        print()


main('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\TheBrothersKaramazov.txt')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i allowed myself to change your joining pattern which made a double space. you must import module `re`

```
def list_to_str_format(line_length=80):
    global big_list
    whole = "".join(str(i) for i in big_list)
    regex = re.compile('(.*?(\s))*')
    while whole != "":
        break_pos = regex.match(whole[:line_length]).end()
        print(whole[:break_pos])
        whole = whole[break_pos:]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was trying to do without taking up copious lines to do so! Much appreciated.